# Why Should one define his own procedure/function while using a DBMS?

Tags: rdbms, database

This might be an odd question but I've been wondering, if a database is well architected, why should one define custom procedures/functions ?
 What are those functions/procedures for ?

 I think I could get a lot of minus votes but I couldn't resist : )

Let me explain why I wonder. At the current work place, other developers use functions/procedures to cut a string that has multiple values seperated by commas.
In my humble opinion, this could have been achieved withoud such functions.

So what are other situations where defining and using a function or procedure is legit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to engineer  a DBMS to cater all possible scopes of potential applications (of DBMS). Although it is possible to have a built in function to tokenise the comma-separated valued string, nothing prevents an application needing to do the same for semi-colon separated one and so on.

Ability to define custom functions and procedures are natural way to extend the capability of the application or adaptability of the DBMS for varying situations.

In terms of legitimacy, it is a hard thing to define. Possibly, your company may have code repository consisting of commonly used functions or procedures to be re-used.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom storad procedures to solve infinity problems.

Easy administration data;
Create operations with transaction control.
Optimization of applications on multiple operations, executing single request to dbms and the dbms execute multiple.
...

But, many developers says that is bad practice or have bad smell.

Comment: Yes, to my nose, it smells funny. It feels like doing some kind of work in a jsp file which should be done in a servlet. I like your last line haha thanks @

Answer (score 0):

Use of functions and procedure makes your DBMS more flexible eg
DECLARE
  -- type books is record

```
  (title  varchar(50),

   author  varchar(50),

  subject varchar(100),

  book_id   number);
```

book1 books;

book2 books;

PROCEDURE printbook (book books) IS

BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line ('Book  title :  ' || book.title);

dbms_output.put_line('Book  author : ' || book.author);

dbms_output.put_line( 'Book  subject : ' || book.subject);

dbms_output.put_line( 'Book book_id : ' || book.book_id);

END;

BEGIN
   -- Book 1 specification

book1.title  := 'C Programming';

book1.author := 'Nuha Ali ';

book1.subject := 'C Programming Tutorial';

book1.book_id := 6495407;

-- Book 2 specification

book2.title := 'Telecom Billing';

book2.author := 'Zara Ali';

book2.subject := 'Telecom Billing Tutorial';

book2.book_id := 6495700;

-- Use procedure to print book info

printbook(book1);

printbook(book2);

END;

/
in above "printbook" function make your query smaller and easy